# Syntax error with Cloud 9?

Tags: python, cloud9-ide

I'm new to Cloud 9, and have made a script. I want the code to appear at the url https://python-william1835.c9.io and I receive the following message:

```
Important: use os.getenv(PORT, 8080) as the port and os.getenv(IP,0.0.0.0) as the host in your scripts!
```

when I run it.

So I put it in the script (along with `import os` of course). And when I run it again, it says:

```
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/Python Projects/Python Enigma Program/main.py", line 14                                                                                
os.getenv(IP, 0.0.0.0)                                                                                                                                            
                  ^                                                                                                                                               
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you tell me why it does this?

Comment: Apologies for the formatting!

Comment: Try `os.getenv("IP", "0.0.0.0")`

Comment: Now is says `NameError: name 'PORT' is not defined`

Comment: Same as with IP, `os.getenv("PORT", 8080)`

Comment: Now there's no errors in the script, but nothing appears at https://python-william1835.c9.io. Am I suppose to have something that uses that site?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I've tried using strings as well. Still, always the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You get a `SyntaxError` because the literal `0.0.0.0` is syntactically invalid.

The message you're receiving is a bit misleading in this specific case. Additionally, the documentation page for `os.getenv` *[is unfortunately not as verbose as one would want](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getenv)*.

But, if you look at the *[source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/os.py#l814)* for `getenv` you'll see that all arguments must be of type `str`:

```
def getenv(key, default=None):
    """Get an environment variable, return None if it doesn't exist.
    The optional second argument can specify an alternate default.
    key, default and the result are str."""
    return environ.get(key, default)
```

Changing your calls to:

```
os.getenv("PORT", "8080") 
os.getenv("IP", "0.0.0.0")
```

Should work and you should have no problem using them.